# Create custom alt + control keys in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, special-characters

Is it possible to create custom keyboard shortcuts on Windows 10 to generate characters that aren't featuring on your keyboard ?
In my case I often need the ß character but it's not featuring on my keyboard. I can get this character with the ALT+225 combination but I think it would be more easy if I could use for instance ALT GR + S (like there is now the standard € character with the ALT GR + E combination.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with a tool such as AutoHotKey from https://www.autohotkey.com/

Your ahk script would I **believe** be

`<^>!:S
!c::Send {U+00DF}
return`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I never heard about AutoHotKey, meanwhile I could "write" the script too, it was like this: `<^>!s::
Send, ß
return`

Comment: Interesting, but if I remember well, this was a built-in Windows feature in older versions (Windows 95, NT 4, XP), it was not necessary to install a new soft.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example (ß), I use the United States-International keyboard layout on my computer, which specifically assigns that character to the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> keystroke. However, for the more general case, you might want to consider using a keymacro program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com).

Comment: I used to use that keystroke AltGr + s heavily as well in the past BUT this has somehow stopped working correctly around the WIN11 update (so not sure if it has to do with WIN11 or other Apps eg I also heard Evernote blocks that key-combo with some non-customizable screen-capture combo, despite the screenshots not showing up in there so I doubt that)

Comment: @GWD - check your settings and make sure that your keyboard is still set for US-International (or some other keyboard config that uses that stroke). I've discovered that sometimes (seemingly randomly) my computer switches to the ENG-US keyboard.

Comment: I managed to identify DELL Display Manager (DDM) as the application "blocking" that special character. Even though there is no shortcut in DDM assigned to it - eg I can print § (via "Right Alt + Shift +s") but "Right Alt + s" outputs nothing. As soon as I Exit/Close the DDM program Right Alt +s will work again. Dell (its monitors, lap[tops, etc) products just seem to have been going down the drain for some time now - seems DDM just got added to that list. Since it in prior versions DDM did not interfere with that keystroke ... still thanks for the hint.